# Automatically Load Django Fixture

Tags: python, django, fixtures, django-fixtures

I'm running Django 1.7. My file tree for the project is as such:

```
/project/app/fixtures/initial_data.json
/project/app/settings.py
```

I know I can run the python `manage.py loaddata app/fixtures/initial_data.json` command that will work for populating my database but I want to load it automatically when `python manage.py migrate` is run. My settings include:

```
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/app/fixtures/'),
)
```

But the fixture is not applied when migrate is run. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm afraid not and this is not your problem, because this is deprecated since Django 1.7:

[READ HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures)

> Automatically loading initial data fixtures¶
>
> Deprecated since version 1.7: If an application uses migrations, there
>   is no automatic loading of fixtures. Since migrations will be required
>   for applications in Django 1.9, this behavior is considered
>   deprecated. If you want to load initial data for an app, consider
>   doing it in a data migration.
>
> If you create a fixture named initial_data.[xml/yaml/json], that
>   fixture will be loaded every time you run migrate. This is extremely
>   convenient, but be careful: remember that the data will be refreshed
>   every time you run migrate. So don’t use initial_data for data you’ll
>   want to edit.

If you really want this to work, you can always customise your `manage.py`,

```
# import execute_from_command_line
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    # add these lines for loading data
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'migrate':
        execute_from_command_line(['manage.py', 'loaddata'])

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will extend the answer. If you need to load specific fixture, than write:
`execute_from_command_line(['manage.py', "loaddata", "my_specific_fixture_name.json"])`

Comment: @AlexeiMarinichenko, nice addon! It makes more sense to capture the extra argument and pass on to `manage.py` command :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can always create a custom migration file that loads fixtures. thus they won't be refreshed every time you run some commands, check this example I want to populate countries, cities, etc.

```
# world/migrations/0002_fixtures.py

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db import migrations


def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    fixture_labels = ['geoname_currency.json', 'geoname_country.json',
                      'geoname_region.json', 'geoname_subregion.json']
    call_command('loaddata', *[
        'world/fixtures/{}'.format(fixture)
        for fixture in fixture_labels
    ])


def reverse_func(apps, schema_editor):
    models = [
        apps.get_model("world", model_name)
        for model_name in ['Subregion', 'Region', 'Currency', 'Country']
    ]
    for model in models:
        model.objects.all().delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('world', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, reverse_func)
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not enough points to be able to comment! This post is quite old... (Django 1.7 - 1.9)
Changing Manage.py is still a valid option to go!

- A reminder to change "migrate" to "makemigrations"

`if len(sys.argv) == 2 and (sys.argv[1] == 'makemigrations'):`

Plus, for the people who don't often read the comments, add your JSON file to the "execute_from_command_line" function.

`execute_from_command_line(['manage.py', 'loaddata', 'YourFileName.json'])`

This way by running `python manage.py makemigrations` it will automatically load your fixture data stated in that file given hard-coded.

Needless to mention, every time you run that command it will override any data modification made to the models in that fixture.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in a similar requirement. I needed to aggregate and load fixtures across all apps in my project with a single command.

`python manage.py loaddata --all` should have sufficed but for some weird reasons - `FIXTURE_DIRS` in my project settings wasn't getting read. Thus, I tweaked `manage.py` file.

```
...
from project.settings import FIXTURE_DIRS

def main():
    ...
     if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == "loaddata" and sys.argv[2] == "--all":
        for fixtures_folder in FIXTURE_DIRS:
            fixtures = [filename for filename in os.listdir(fixtures_folder) if filename.endswith(".json")]
            for fixture in fixtures:
                fixture_path = os.path.join(fixtures_folder, fixture)
                command = f"python manage.py loaddata {fixture_path}"
                os.system(command)
                print(f"{fixture_path} completed")
    else:
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

`python manage.py loaddata --all` can be ran successfully after migrating necessary changes to the DB.